# Invalid function in ruby

Tags: ruby, function, methods, syntax-error

Why is this function invalid?

```
def request(method='get',resource, meta={}, strip=true)

end
```

unexcpected ')' expecting keyword_end

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a function. It's a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby, you can't surround a required parameter with optional parameters. Using

```
def request(resource, method='get', strip=true, meta={})
end
```

will solve the issue.

As a thought experiment, consider the original function

```
def request(method='get',resource, meta={}, strip=true)
end
```

If I call that method as `request(object)`, the desired behavior is fairly obvious -- call the method with `object` as the `resource` parameter. But what if I call it as `request('post', object)`? Ruby would need to understand the semantics of `method` to decide whether `'post'` is the `method` or the `resource`, and whether `object` is the `resource` or the `meta`. This is beyond the scope of Ruby's parser, so it simply throws an invalid function error.

**A couple additional tips:**

I would also put the meta argument last, which allows you to pass the hash options in without curly braces, such as:

```
request(object, 'get', true, foo: 'bar', bing: 'bang')
```

As Andy Hayden pointed out in the comments, the following function works:

```
def f(aa, a='get', b, c); end
```

It's generally good practice to place all your optional parameters at the end of the function to avoid the mental gymnastics required to follow calls to a function like this.

Comment: except you can, `def f(aa, a='get', b, c); end` ...?

Comment: Whoops -- it looks like it's actually just that you can't sandwich a required parameter between non-required parameters. I'm guessing the Ruby parser doesn't know how to handle this case. Updating my answer.

Comment: @AndyHayden, I added some additional clarification that hopefully explains why the original method fails a little more effectively.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for updating :) I was/am kind of shocked that is allowed tbh!

Comment: @Kyle re your thought experiment, I disagree, I think `request(object)` should not work (which does seem to make sandwiched default args redundant... you should be able to keyword it `request(resource=object)` (but I don't think you can in ruby) :(

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one group of optional parameters in a parameter list.

A pseudo-regex for parameter lists in Ruby is something like this:

```
mand* opt* splat? mand* (mand_kw | opt_kw)* kwsplat? block?
```

Here's an example:

```
def foo(m1, m2, o1=:o1, o2=:o2, *splat, m3, m4, 
          ok1: :ok1, mk1:, mk2:, ok2: :ok2, **ksplat, &blk)
  Hash[local_variables.map {|var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }]
end

method(:foo).arity
# => -5

method(:foo).parameters
# => [[:req, :m1], [:req, :m2], [:opt, :o1], [:opt, :o2], [:rest, :splat], 
#     [:req, :m3], [:req, :m4], [:keyreq, :mk1], [:keyreq, :mk2], 
#     [:key, :ok1], [:key, :ok2], [:keyrest, :ksplat], [:block, :blk]]

foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
# ArgumentError: missing keywords: mk1, mk2

foo(1, 2, 3, mk1: 4, mk2: 5)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4+)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, mk1: 5, mk2: 6)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: :o1, o2: :o2, splat: [], m3: 3, m4: 4, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 5, mk2: 6, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, mk1: 6, mk2: 7)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: :o2, splat: [], m3: 4, m4: 5, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 6, mk2: 7, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, mk1: 7, mk2: 8)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [], m3: 5, m4: 6, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 7, mk2: 8, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, mk1: 8, mk2: 9)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5], m3: 6, m4: 7, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 8, mk2: 9, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, mk1: 9, mk2: 10)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 9, mk2: 10, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13, k4: 14}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
      ok1: 9, ok2: 10, mk1: 11, mk2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14) do 15 end
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13, k4: 14}, 
#      blk: #<Proc:0xdeadbeefc00l42@(irb):15> }
```

[Note: mandatory keyword arguments will be introduced in Ruby 2.1, all the rest already works.]

Answer (score 1):

Try reordering your parameters:

```
def Request(resource,strip=true,method='get',meta={})
end
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but why, actually I need to enter these variables in order